# Is there a way to color all the equations with same color in desmos

Tags: desmos

I am trying to plot a image in desmos graphing calculator. I am extracting Bezier curves of the image from svg format of the image. There are totally 2134 curves, when I plot, desmos assigns different color to each curve. Is there a way I can color all the curves with same color other than manually changing color of each curve.

Answer (score 0):

One could make a list of curves.
For example,
[image: robphy-Desmos-example]